# How to get JSON response array all index values?

Tags: ios, json, object

I need to get JSON response array all indexes values and maintain separate array. Here below I have posted my JSON response and I wanted to get console output looks like below also. Please help me.

```
response : [ {

        A =  [  {

                    name : "sons";
                    age = [
                                4
                          ];
                },
                {
                    name : "rondo";
                    age = [
                                2
                          ];
                },

             ];


           } ]
```

I need to store separate array separate values looks like below console output

```
2014-09-18 10:24:39.461 Myapp[1133:60b] RESULT : {
    name = "sons";
    age  = 4;
}
2014-09-18 10:24:39.462 Myapp[1133:60b] RESULT : {
    name = "rondo";
    age  = 2;
}
```

Here below I tried but I Know I can get only 0th index value but I need to get all index value from JSON response array:

```
myvalue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[[responsData objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"A"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"name"]];
```

Comment: how far did you try ?

Comment: you need to parse the json and generate the new one with your desire format

Comment: No. I need to get looks like above console output from #1 JSON response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get all objects, get the array using the respective key.Then store the result in another array by iterating the for loop according to array count.

```
NSArray *recordsArr = [[responsedata objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"A"];

NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < [recordsArr count]; i ++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *recordDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordDict setObject:[[recordsArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
    [recordDict setObject:[[[recordsArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"age"] objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"age"];

    [resultArray addObject:recordDict];
}

NSLog(@"%@",resultArray);
```

output:

```
2014-09-18 12:49:22.047 testprj[1044:60b] (
        {
        age = 4;
        name = sons;
    },
        {
        age = 2;
        name = rondo;
    }
)
```

Comment: Your answer really great and very helping for me. Btw above you should remove  [objectAtIndex:0] for age value getting. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you are welcome. I jus wrote the code according to output. u can modify the code according to your desired output :)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *strName = (NSString *) [yourArray valueForKey:@"name"];
NSInteger age = [(NSNumber *) [yourArray valueForKey:@"age"] integerValue];
```

Comment: you can create array instead of string and integer, then you will get all your data at once in an array