# How to get array of array value count?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I need to get JSON response array "A" of [value count]. Here below I have posted my JSON response. Please help me.

```
response : [ {

        A =  [  {

                    name : "sons";
                    age = [
                                4
                          ];
                },
                {
                    name : "rondo";
                    age = [
                                2
                          ];
                },

             ];


           } ]



NSArray *firstObject = @"A";
NSArray *count = [[[responsData objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:firstObject]valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Here below my current console output :

```
2014-09-18 16:32:36.746 Myapp[4243:60b] TEST   : (
    sons,
    rondo
)
```

I need looks like below "name value count"

```
2014-09-18 16:32:36.746 Myapp[4243:60b] TEST   : (

     2
)
```

Comment: Why do you keep duplicating: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904576/how-to-get-json-response-array-all-index-values ? You only have a small change each time, but you need to read of deserialize JSON.

Comment: Just call count on NSArray

Comment: Try actually reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
     NSArray *count = [[[responsData objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:firstObject]valueForKey:@"name"];
     NSLog(@"count == %d",[count count]);
```

Comment: Thanks. How to convert [count count] to NSString?

Comment: NSString *myCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[count count]];
    NSLog(@"myCount == %@",myCount);

Comment: Thank you @S R Nayak. Great helping.